Quick question about a possible typo concerning definition for inverse limit for the inverse systems of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then , the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 3:  An inverse system of groups (respectively topological groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc) is  a family $G_i, i\in I$, of groups, together with a fmaily of homomorphisms $f_{ij}:G_i\to G_j,i\succeq j$ such that :

$f_{ii}=1_{G_i}.$

Whenever $i\succeq j \succeq k,$ then $f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}.$


Definition 4:  The inverse (or projective) limit of the inverse system of groups $G_i,$ is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism $$\phi_i:G\to G_i$$
for each $i\in I$ satisfying

If $i \succeq j$ then $\phi_j= f_{ij}\circ \phi_i$, i.e. the homomorphism $\phi_i$ are compatible with the inverse system.

Given another group $H$ and $\psi_i:G_i\to H$ compatible with the inverse system, then there is a unique homomorphism $\psi:H\to G$ such that $\psi_i=\phi_i\circ \psi$ for any $i \in I$.
We write


$$G=\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i$$.
In the categories of sets, groups, rings etc., inverse limits alwaysexist and admit the following description:
$$\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i=\{(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i\mid f_{ji}(g_j)=g_i \text{ for all }i\preceq j\}$$.
Questions:
I have a quick questions on wordings and possible misprints about Definition 4 above,
In $1.$ for Definition 4, above, should $\phi_j= f_{ij}\circ \phi_i$ be $\phi_j=\phi_{ij}\circ \phi_i$ instead?
Thank you in advance

No. Where did you see $\phi_{ij}$ is the definition anyway?

@Mark I ask a related question about direct limit and given how the composition maps are written in that definition, and that the book where I got the two definitions has mistakes.  I thought I should check with the experts on here.  So the definition written here:  $\phi_j= f_{ij}\circ \phi_i$ for Definition 4 $1.$ is correct?

As I see, in this definition $\phi_{ij}$ also wasn't defined, so there it should also be $f_{ij}$.

@Mark would the map:  $\phi_j= f_{ij}\circ \phi_i$ be written out in terms  of arrow map notations as:  $G\xrightarrow{\phi_{j}}G_j=G\xrightarrow{\phi_i}G_i\xrightarrow{f_{ij}}G_j$?

Yes. If you learn about inverse limits you are probably already familiar with composition of functions.

@Mark can I trouble you about the following two follow up post and post, on notations.  That is if you have a few moments.  I just want to make sure I am understanding the notations correctly.  Thank you in advance.

I see we are again keeping our sources under a seal of secrecy for no good reason whatsoever.

@ArturoMagidin thanks for noticing.  I thought I added the source.  My posts about direct and inverse limits are all taken from the same sources.  There will be a post where I will cite additional ones but that have to do with asking about a different concept relating to it.
